# Find out if it was request or not without Notice

Tags: php, request, notice

I want to have code like this:

```
If(...)
{
   //do if there was a request GET or POST
}
else
{
   //do if not
}
```

How to make this happen? Solutions like this: `if($_POST['name'])` let php to throw notice.

Comment: @chris85 - Your first solution will only validate if both `$_GET` and `$_POST` is set.

Comment: Oh yea, that's an `and` not `or` check. Good point @MagnusEriksson. You could use $_REQUEST but that also includes cookies.

Comment: *"let php to throw notice"* - What do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **PHP**'s [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['param_name']) || isset($_GET['param_name'])) {

} else {

}
```

> **isset()** determines if a variable is set and is not NULL

---

As @Fred suggested, We can also use PHP's [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. Like this:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST['param_name']) || !empty($_GET['param_name'])) {

    } else {

    }
```

> **empty()** determines whether a variable is empty or not.

---

Difference between **isset()** and **empty()**.

[image]

Comment: `!empty()` is better if it's a text input.

Comment: I like the graphic you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use isset() function of php

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_GET['name']))
{
   //do if there was a request GET or POST
}
else
{
   //do if not
}
```

Comment: `!empty()` is better if it's a text input.